# Time game (hours, minutes, seconds)

Tags: c

first thanks watching. i tried to take an input (hour, minute, second, duration (seconds) )
and convert all to a total hour of arrival.

i got a problem when i enter this numbers : "23 59 59 10801".
what i am expecting to get is "arrival time - > 3 0 0 "
but actually i get nothing.

(every other positive number works just fine...)
thank for help, sorry if my code is a total mess.
:)

```
int h = 0, m = 0, s = 0, time = 0, ih = 0, im = 0, is = 0;

printf("please enter 4 digits\n");
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &h, &m, &s, &time);

if ((((h<=23)&&(h>0)) && ((m<=59) && (m>0)) && ((s<=59) && (s>0))) && (time > 0))
{
    //  hour loop

    while (time >= 3600) {
        ++ih;
        time = (time - 3600);

        //  minute loop
        while ((time < 3600) && (time != 0)) {
            ++im;
            time = (time - 60);

            //  second loop
            while ((time <= 60) && (time != 0)) {
                ++is;
                time = (time - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    h = (h + ih);
    m = (m + im);
    s = (s + is);

    if (h >= 24) {
        h = ((h * 0) + ih-1);
    }

    if (m = 60) {
        m = (m * 0);
        ++h;
    }

    if (s = 60) {
        s = (s * 0);
        ++m;
    }

    printf("\nwe are happy to annonce that:\n\nyour arival time will be at : %d %d %d\n\n\nhave a nice day!\n\n\n\n", h, m, s);

}
else printf("\nwrong value my friend!\n\n");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: So many parentheses! Learn that operator precedence table!

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? What does `23 59 59 10801` mean? Is `10801` a date formatted in some way?

Comment: @szczurcio yes, 10801(seconds) is 3 hours, 1 sec.

23:59:59 + 3 hors and 1 sec should get me 3:00:00 .

Comment: `m = (m * 0);` is the same as `m=0` and that is more readable

Comment: all your while's can be reduced to modulo-operations

Comment: @PeterMiehle i dont really know how to do it with just modulo

Comment: `ih = time % 3600; time = time - (3600*ih); im = time % 60; time = time - (60*im); is = time;`

Answer (score 3):

`if (m = 60)` sets `m` to `60` and is true. You want to write `if (m == 60)`.

The same for `if (s = 60)`